# Build OpencvBlobsLib in Windows Environment

Tags: opencv, pthreads, cvblobslib

How to perform the build `OpenCVBlobsLib` Lib in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (works on previous versions)

Comment: just be warned, that cvBlobsLib is from times of opencv1.0, the code is very outdated, and rather should be avoided. you probably can do whatever you want with opencv's onboard functions.

Comment: Is OpencvBlobsLib: http://opencvblobslib.github.io/opencvblobslib/

Comment: ah, ok. mistook it for the old one.

Comment: you can remove the down vote?

Comment: not mine, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step (I put this tutorial in github issues but closed)

1. I download your cvBlobslib (https://github.com/OpenCVBlobsLib/opencvblobslib)
2. I create an Empty Project in Visual Studio 2013
3. I put the 6 .h and 5 .cpp in the project
4. I Binding all OpenCV dependencies (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-VgWxkVp2w)
5. I download this file: pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release.zip 1.17MB 
   and Unzip in this Folder: C:\pthreads.hWin32 (I create this folder)
6. This folder had 3 Subfolders: "Pre-built.2" , "pthreads.2" , "QueueUserAPCEx".
7. "Pre-built.2" had 3 Subfolders: "lib"(2 Subfolders: x64 with libpthreadGC2.a(Exetension .a) and pthreadVC2.lib, x86 I don't use it), "dll", "include" with 3 .h files.
8. I add "include" in "Additional include directories".
9. I add "lib" in "Additional library directory".
10. I add "pthreadVC2.lib" (inside lib folder)
11. change the "Configuration Type" in Configuration Properties -->> General to Static Library .lib
12. I add this Line above all includes and in All .cpp: 
    `#pragma warning(disable: 4996)//This function or variable may be unsafe`
13. in main menu I select `Release / x64` and I click in "BUILD" -->> "Build Solution"
14. In folder: `C:\Users\Ricardo\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\cvBlobsLib\x64\Release`
    Had `cvBlobsLib.lib` with 11.554 KB.

You can download the Result here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bctrg3o8jihnf2r/cvBlobsLib.lib